# Dynamically allocate SIMD Vector as array of doubles

Tags: c, vector, simd

I'm new to vectors and I've been having a read of the [gcc documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html) trying to get my head around it.

Is it possible to dynamically allocate the size of a vector at run time? It appears as though you have to do this in the typedef like:

```
typedef double v4sf __attribute__((vector_size (16)));
```

I want to set the values of the vector to an array of doubles. I've tried like so:

```
v4sf curr_vect = double_array;
```

Where double_array is obviously an array of doubles. But this fails to compile. Is it possible to do either of these things?

Comment: How about `double *vec = malloc(sizeof(*vec) * 16;`?

Comment: @H2CO3 That won't be properly aligned.

Comment: @Mysticial Oh, excuse me. In that case, `posix_memalign()` should do the trick.

Comment: @H2CO3 Yeah, that will work.

Comment: @Mysticial Do you mind if I write an answer?

Answer (score 2):

If your platform is POSIX-compliant, you can achieve aligned dynamic memory allocation using the [`posix_memalign()` function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/posix_memalign.html):

```
double *p;
if (posix_memalign((void **)&p, 16, sizeof(*p) * 16) != 0) {
    perror("posix_memalign");
    abort();
}

p[0] = 3.1415927;
// ...

free(p);
```

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but where do I then declare and initialise the vector?

Comment: @rheotron You won't then have a `typedef`. It will simply be `double *vector;` as in the example. You allocate aligned memory, then you assign each member a value.

Comment: Ah - I see what you mean. It seems to be allocating the memory correctly. Though, it doesn't seem to be doing vector subtraction. Any ideas?

Comment: @rheotron It should. "it doesn't seem to be doing vector subtraction correctly" - precisely what's the error? Where's your code?

Comment: Tried pasting the code here. Didn't work - linked it here: http://pastebin.com/fdTaCkBj

Comment: @rheotron Huh? That 1. leaks memory when you assign `array_one` and `array_two` to `a` and `b`, 2. This does pointer subtraction. I don't think that's what you want. I advise you to learn basic C memory management before trying to engange in advanced optimization techniques.

Comment: Ok - I think I understand a bit more now. What I want to be able to do is vector subtraction, sorry, perhaps I should have been more clear in my initial question. Does this solution not address that problem?

Comment: @rheotron No, this answer only answers the question you asked. For me it wasn't clear you were also asking about a certain math problem (in fact, you weren't).